# need to remove orderBy filter on ng repeat on condition basis

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

In my AngularJS application by default, I have `$scope.initialLoad = false`. In that case I need to have ng-repeat as `ng-repeat="tab in logBookCtrl.tempLoadTabsToDeleted |  orderBy:'age' "`, as shown below.

```
<tab sortable-tab  ng-repeat="tab in logBookCtrl.tempLoadTabsToDeleted |  orderBy:'age' "
     active="tab.active" ng-click="selectMainTab(tab)">
</tab>
```

But  in my controller whenever I make `$scope.initialLoad = true;` that `orderBy` filer should not be applied. Means it should be normal ng-repeat

```
<tab sortable-tab ng-repeat="tab in logBookCtrl.tempLoadTabsToDeleted  " 
     active="tab.active" ng-click="selectMainTab(tab)">
</tab>
```

Means that orderBy filter should not be applied whenever  `$scope.initialLoad` becomes `true` in my controller. How can I do it?

Comment: You can try making the orderBy value a variable and setting it to an empty string when $scope.initialLoad is true

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but try something like:

`$scope.orderBy = 'key';`

```
<tab sortable-tab ng-repeat="(key, tab) in logBookCtrl.tempLoadTabsToDeleted | orderBy: orderBy" active="tab.active" ng-click="selectMainTab(tab)"></tab>
```

This way when they are unordered they will order by the array index (original ordering)